# How to check if Rating setting is enabled Sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I've checked this link:

[How to Check Rating Settings is enabled or not by Javascript in SharePoint 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598301/how-to-check-rating-settings-is-enabled-or-not-by-javascript-in-sharepoint-2010)

but this does not work for the lists once that you have already activated (and deactivated) the rating setting, at least not on Sharepoint 2013.

I've also checked that there's a ReputationHelper class within the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Portal.dll  and it is used to activate or deactivate this feature:

http://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/enable-rating-likes-settings-in-sharepoint-2013/

so I've tried to open the dll using visual studio but somehow that class is internal, and I wasn't able to inspect the methods. Even used powershell to load the assembly and try to create an instance for that class but it also failed.

Do you know if that class has a method call that allows to get the specific value of this Rating Setting on a list?. I've tried just with GetReputation (a lucky guess), but it did not work.

I've also tried to get the list schema using the rest service http://sp.mydomain.com/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Pages') but the schema does not display any property for this. Do  you know a way to get this value for an specific list even when it has been already activated before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be done via JavaScript?

You can try to see what the EnableReputation method does when the ratings/likes are already enabled, maybe it returns a value, though I'm not sure how you can get a return value for that method. Here's the code I have that enables the Likes programmatically on any given list:

```
private void ActivateLikesOnList(SPList list)
{
  try
  {
    System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c");
    Type reputationHelper = assembly.GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.ReputationHelper");
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = reputationHelper.GetMethod("EnableReputation", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    method.Invoke(null, new Object[] { list, "Likes", false });
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    String msg = "Error while activating Likes on List" + " : {0} :: {1} :: {2}";
    _DiagnosticService.WriteTrace(0, _DiagnosticCategory, TraceSeverity.Medium, msg, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.TargetSite);
  }
}
```

I hope this gives you a hint on how you can achieve that.